# Video Hosting External or Internal?

Tags: video, video-streaming

I have a client who wants to offer videos for downloading or streaming on his website. Now we have hosting for him, which is wonderful: it's reliable and fast, offers unlimited space and databases BUT it only offers 10GB in bandwidth.

The videos could easily be placed on his server (unlimited space) but the bandwidth is a real problem.

Now I am wondering if he would purchase external hosting for his videos, and people would want to download them, woould this still eat up all his available bandwidth in no time, because the download request would go via his site, or is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: 10GB bandwidth (highly unlikely) or 10GB traffic allowance over some given time period, usually per month?

Comment: Yes, per month.

Answer (score 0):

If your reaching 10GB then best way to host on AWS with Drawin

Comment: Yes that is the hosting solution I have in mind. So far no one has really answered my question though. Will hosting at and external provider eat the bandwidth?

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into something like youtube, or vimeo etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Brightcove http://www.brightcove.com/en/ as I find they are the leaders in premium video streaming.  Ping me back if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you host it on another site (Vimeo, S3, NimbusHD, etc) it would not eat up your bandwidth... When you embed a video, your browser is normally pulling it straight from the video hosting provider.